# Thymefelaf th:text in a class attribute for a given html tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot, Thymeleaf & Bootstrap application. I have lots of components in the GUI and some of them share the same bootstrap color value. I am changing the color often and it is really troublesome to go through the code and find & update all components with the same color.

I want to do something like that:

in my `messages.properties` file I will have something like this:

```
login_modal_header_color=purple darken-4
```

and be able to get that value in a class attribute like this:

```
<div class="modal-header text-center th:text='#{login_modal_header_color}'">
```

The problem is, when you use `th:text='#{login_modal_header_color}'` inside of `" "` then it's just a text and thymeleaf doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use `th:classappend`:

```
<div class="modal-header text-center" th:classappend="#{login_modal_header_color}">
```